# Why is an empty embed block displayed?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

What I have done wrong here?

models.py

```
main_vid = EmbedBlock(
        template='wtblocks/main_vid.html',
        label="Video",
        icon='image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

main_vid.html

```
{% load wagtailcore_tags wagtailimages_tags  %}
{% load wagtailembeds_tags %}

<div class="container container-block main_vid">

    {% embed self.main_vid %}

</div>
```

I look in the inspector, this block turns out to be empty. If I do not use `template = 'wtblocks / main_vid.html'`, then the video is displayed well for me, but I just can't style it.

Comment: EmbedVideoField isn't a standard field in Wagtail: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/search?q=EmbedVideoField&unscoped_q=EmbedVideoField -- is it from https://django-embed-video.readthedocs.io/ instead?

Comment: @SteveJalim I updated the question, maybe you could help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use {{Self}} only, but you can't call the self object as it's instance.

```html
    {% load wagtailcore_tags wagtailimages_tags wagtailembeds_tags %}

    <div class="container container-block main_vid">

        {% embed self %}
    </div>
```

*note that this code can't be running here, as it is a django-template